# Является ли словосочетание "особенности и нюансы" плеоназмом?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, плеоназм

Например, "особенности и нюансы серебристого мелирования", "особенности и нюансы выращивания томатов" и т. п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Особенности и нюансы.***

**Здесь нет плеоназма, то есть дублирования смысла.**

**ОСОБЕННОСТЬ**, Характерное, отличительное свойство, качество, признак кого-, чего-л. **НЮАНС,** 2. Мелкая подробность чего-л., тонкость.

Например, есть (1) **общие правила** выращивания овощей, а есть (2) **особенности** выращивания отдельных культур (томатов). И кроме этого, есть (3) **отдельные нюансы**  этого процесса, то есть небольшие детали, приемы, получаемые обычно опытным путем.